# Difference between supplemental noun phrase and absolute clause?

Tags: meaning, verbs, american-english, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

What is the difference between a supplemental noun phrase and a absolute clause? In these examples and in general. Is it just **the non-finite** nature of the second example? Are they not serving a similar purpose?

> He won at his favourite sport, the long-jump, and brought another medal home for the U.S, **the most fitting *conclusion* to his brilliant career in track and field.**

*Noun phrase functioning as a supplement/ syntactically separate element.*

> He just stood there, **his face clearly revealing his disappointment.**

*Absolute clause: called absolute because it serves no grammatical function in the sentence. It just adds supplemental information.*

Comment: Isn’t one important difference that one is an NP—a phrase headed by a noun, that acts like a noun—and the other is a clause?

Comment: @sumelic That's obviously an important **formal** difference, but I suspect what the OP is after is a functional difference?

Comment: Is the first example taken from a printed source? I'd expect something more heavyweight than a comma before such a fragment (a full stop, even). There's arguably a deleted subject + verb (...; this was ...).

Answer (score 0):

An absolute clause must include both a subject ("his face") and a predicate ("clearly revealing his disappointment"). Your first example ("the most fitting conclusion to his brilliant career in track and field") is just a single noun phrase.

Comment: 'He just stood there, his face a picture of disappointment' might prove more tricky to pin down.