# Usage with noun phrases

Tags: meaning, verbs, american-english

> During the interview he promoted a new book, *his brutally honest and  funny memoir.*

So this is a noun phrase in apposition, but is that what defines it as a noun phrase in this example (being in apposition)?

I would have thought '*a brutally honest and funny memoir*' would be a noun phrase, as there is no subject.

> He just stood there, *his face clearly revealing his disappointment.*

This is an absolute phrase, but has a subject like the first example but contains a non-finite structure.

So other than that and their difference in usage here, they are similar: his memoir/his face.

Comment: I think you mean ‘Apposition’ (not ‘Opposition’). I have edited accordingly.  The phrase in italic is a participial noun phrase.

Comment: Sorry:  I hit the send button by mistake.  In Latin it would be described as ‘in apposition’ [which only really means ‘put next to’, but in a sense that allows apposition to indicate a semantic or syntactic proximity].  To what it is in apposition is   uncertain, I think.  This could be the noun ‘he’ - it enlarges on (tells us more about HIM); it could be to the verb (tells us more about what he was DOING);  or it might be to the entire clause.  I am not familiar with how this grammatical is treated by modern grammarians.  But I am think it is in apposition to the clause as a whole.

Comment: Isn't this a lot like your previous question: [Difference between supplemental NP and absolute clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478117)

Answer (score 1):

> During the interview he promoted a new book, *his brutally honest and funny memoir*.

What makes the italicized portion a noun phrase is not its function (e.g., being in apposition) but the fact that the head of the phrase (*memoir*) is classified as a noun.

> He just stood there, *his face clearly revealing his disappointment*.

Here, the italicized portion is not a noun phrase, because its head is not a noun (e.g., *face* or *disappointment*) but the verb *revealing*. Since it has *his face* as its subject, you can call it a non-finite clause.

Comment: Participle noun phrase: the dog whining for a treat  (head whining) her dog whining for a treat (absolute) same head word whining, so is it not the subject or lack of which defines it as an absolute not just the verb or function of the phrase.

Comment: @bluebell1 You need to give me a full sentence, but the very concept of 'participle noun phrase' is outdated because it's illogical. If the head of a phrase is a participle, it's a verb phrase, not a noun phrase, because 'participle' is a verb.